# SQL QUERY - UPDATE STATEMENT WITH JOIN WITH OTHER TABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

Here is the query that I have come up with but seems not working right.

```
UPDATE ItemDynamic
SET TaxID=8
FROM ItemDynamic
INNER JOIN Item
ON Item.ID = ItemDynamic.ItemID
WHERE Item.DateCreated>'2013-06-18' and StoreID=11 or StoreID=1 or StoreID=2 or StoreID=3
```

DateCreated column is not in the ItemDynamic, this column is in Item table. So I join Item table and ItemDynamic table. The problem is, when I tried to update more stores same time, it updates the whole item.
But when I update only one store, it updates fine. Is there any reason why?

Thanks,

Comment: sounds like you just need brackets `WHERE Item.DateCreated>'2013-06-18' and (StoreID=11 or StoreID=1 or StoreID=2 or StoreID=3)`

Comment: Use `StoreID IN (...)` instead of a bunch of `OR`s

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query, and your `OR` clause should be surrounded with round brackets

```
UPDATE ItemDynamic a 
INNER JOIN Item B
ON b.ID = a.ItemID 
SET a.TaxID=8 
WHERE b.DateCreated>'2013-06-18' 
AND (b.StoreID=11 OR b.StoreID=1 OR b.StoreID=2 OR b.StoreID=3)
```

I assumed `StoreID` and `DateCreated` are in table Item.

Comment: INNER JOIN giving me an error. But I used a_horse_with_no_name gave me the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to test a field against multiple values, I find `IN` to be clearer than a bunch of `OR` tests. And it avoids the `AND`/`OR` precedence problem that you ran into.

```
UPDATE ItemDynamic
INNER JOIN Item
SET TaxID=8
ON Item.ID = ItemDynamic.ItemID
WHERE Item.DateCreated>'2013-06-18'
AND StoreID IN (11, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What was the error? And if you got an answer, you should post it for the benefit of others.